# clarifying the short description of the "sportsmanship" badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sportsmanship-badge, badge-description

The [current description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) of the "Sportsmanship" badge is:

> Up voted 100 competing answers

That misled me at first. I wonder if a few more words might help others avoid the same misunderstanding I made, thinking that "competing answers" referred to any two answers to the same question (i.e. answers that competed with each other, regardless of whether or not I'd answered that question myself), rather than the actual definition: upvoting 100 answers that competed with an answer that **I** had given to a question, and where my answer has a positive score.

So, the revised description could be something like this:

> Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score

Comment: ...or is the accepted answer.  If someone has the accepted answer but zero points, the sportmanship badge should still count if you upvote another answer.

Comment: Right now, an accepted answer with zero points does not count for the sportsmanship badge when you upvote competing answers.  My suggestion was more for the way the badge works than the language describing it.

Comment: @Geoff will it be available in the next build? Can't see any change at the moment.

Comment: Yes, next build @ShaWizDowArd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I agree with the OP, I think the description needs to include "where an answer of yours has a positive score."

I've been wondering where my Sportsmanship badge is, as I feel like I've up-voted more than 100 competing answers, but I didn't know my post also needed to have positive up-votes.

@user unknown has posted a good description, but I think the OP's is best as it includes the extra about the positive score.

Answer (score -2):

Shorter Terminology

> Up voted 100 answers, competing with his own

Comment: -1. Sorry, but your suggestion doesn't explain that your own answers should have a positive score - so I vote against this suggestion.

Comment: also the badge descriptions choose "you" and "your" over "he" and "his" (for which I am grateful)