# A couple of questions on badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I seem to recall a badge that had something along the lines of

> Voted up two competing answers.

or something like that. Has this badge been removed?

What happens to a badge if it is removed entirely from SO. Is the badge count lowered or does it stay intact?

Is there a history of old badges that SO has had, what it did and why it was removed?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confused with the Sportsmanship badge? That requires 100 upvotes on competing posts.

Comment: have a look at [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/173001) and find the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about the [Sportsmanship badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship).

The text was probably changed over time but essentially it means "voted up 100 competing answers".

As for badge removal I strongly believe such thing never happened and never will, but if it does then yes the badge count will decrease as there's no point counting a badge that does not exist.

Comment: I think you're right. Either I remember it wrong or they've changed the description on this tag.

Comment: (Except for tag badges. Those are rescinded if you fall below the threshold, or if the tag gets nuked - quite a few [homework] tag badges are disappearing these days.)

Comment: Correct, we've never removed a public badge.

Comment: @Niklas - you are not wrong. [Here is the source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108883/clarifying-the-short-description-of-the-sportsmanship-badge) - looks like it was changed in Aug 20.

Comment: @Nick thanks, and is this a possibility in the future?

Comment: I don't see this ever happening, we're pretty protective of already-awarded badges.  If a badge is *brand-spanking-new* and is wildly bugged then maybe there would be an extreme case, but even then I doubt it.