# Got answer with 10 upvotes but didn't get the Enlightened badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, enlightened-badge, badge-description

I have this [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891449/1108032). It is accepted and has 10 upvotes (and one downvote) and is the first answer of the question. The last upvote is more than 3 days old. However no Enlightened badge was awarded to me. According to the definition of the badge:

> Enlightened × 58749   First to answer and accepted with at least 10
>   upvotes

However, the rule might be a bit different: not 10 upvotes, but rather score of 10, otherwise why the 3 day delay in distributing the badge?

I am marking the post as bug, because I think either the rule or the definition should be changed.

Comment: This now is unjustified. You can for sure downvote this question of mine if you find it unfitting for the forum. However, downvoting my actual SO answer is just a matter of revenge. People find use in it. Did you find an error in it in order to downvote it?

Comment: Honestly I think people here on Meta are too trigger happy sometimes. +1 from me although I usually stay neutral on such things.

Comment: +1 to compensate the answer.  That was either ridiculous timing, or somebody needs to calm the passive-aggressive act down.

Comment: @CodaFi and others - Well, one thing everyone should keep in mind is upvotes aren't equal compensation. +1 = 10 / -1 = -2.  This is more aimed at people unfairly downvoting though than it is people who are trying to be nice. If everyone just tries to be fair instead, the sympathy upvote problem would exist a lot less.

Comment: @jmort253 I agree to that entirely. The compensation is not fair. The upvote is just as unfair as the downvote - none of the two voters actually even read neither the question nor the answer. Probably they do not even understand the technologies involved.

Comment: @jmort253 Oh, ye of little faith.  Perhaps there could be a little more trust in my (and others) abilities as a developer, before we jump to conclusions.  Yes, I did compensate our friend Boris here, but I also read the question, the answer, and the other answer (which was wrong).

Comment: @CodaFi - lol!! Fair enough ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the [faq here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) does indeed say:

> ### Enlightened
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Be the first person to answer a
>     question, and receive **a score of at least ten** for that answer. The
>     answer must be accepted by the question owner, and it mustn't be a
>     self-accept.

So most likely the badge description is wrong.

Comment: And now goes the question: who has the rights to correct the definition?

Comment: @Boris as far as I know, only the site developers have such power.

Comment: @Boris they roam this Meta site and as you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108883/clarifying-the-short-description-of-the-sportsmanship-badge) fix those things. (Though it might take some time)

Comment: However if I accept your answer will they still look into the bug report?

Comment: Boris, the problem isn't with the description. It's likely a caching issue or a bug. Some badges don't appear right away. If you don't see it in the next couple of days, maybe a dev will see this and take a look.

Comment: @jmort253 I don't agree with you. We already found with Sha two different places (FAQ and badge description) that state different things. At least one of them is wrong for sure.

Comment: Where is the other description?

Comment: @jmort253 he means the faq I linked to; in case it's wrong we can edit it ourselves.

Comment: @jmort253. The links: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges ///// http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions. We have cited both cases.

Comment: Ah, I see now. One says "score" and the other says "upvotes". I'm dense!

Answer (score 5):

The Enlightened badge description was inaccurate. It will be updated in the next build to read:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more